# Is `iter().map().sum()` as fast as `iter().fold()`?

Tags: rust

Does the compiler generate the same code for `iter().map().sum()` and `iter().fold()`? In the end they achieve the same goal, but the first code would iterate two times, once for the `map` and once for the `sum`.

Here is an example. Which version would be faster in `total`?

```
pub fn square(s: u32) -> u64 {
    match s {
        s @ 1...64 => 2u64.pow(s - 1),
        _ => panic!("Square must be between 1 and 64")
    }
}

pub fn total() -> u64 {
    // A fold
    (0..64).fold(0u64, |r, s| r + square(s + 1))
    // or a map
    (1..64).map(square).sum()
}
```

What would be good tools to look at the assembly or benchmark this?

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by *iterate two times*?

Comment: @MatthieuM. a common misconception. Languages like Ruby, for example, will produce an entire `Array` as the result of a `map`. Each chained `map` call thus has to iterate over a new container. There are also "lazy" iterators in Ruby, but they aren't as common.

Comment: @Shepmaster: That's what I am fearing, yes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For them to generate the same code, they'd first have to **do the same thing**. Your two examples do not:

```
fn total_fold() -> u64 {
    (0..64).fold(0u64, |r, s| r + square(s + 1))
}

fn total_map() -> u64 {
    (1..64).map(square).sum()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", total_fold());
    println!("{}", total_map());
}
```

```
18446744073709551615
9223372036854775807
```

---

Let's assume you meant

```
fn total_fold() -> u64 {
    (1..64).fold(0u64, |r, s| r + square(s + 1))
}

fn total_map() -> u64 {
    (1..64).map(|i| square(i + 1)).sum()
}
```

There are a few avenues to check:

1. The generated LLVM IR
2. The generated assembly
3. Benchmark

The *easiest* source for the IR and assembly is one of the playgrounds ([official](https://play.rust-lang.org) or [alternate](http://play.integer32.com)). These both have buttons to view the assembly or IR. You can also pass `--emit=llvm-ir` or `--emit=asm` to the compiler to generate these files.

Make sure to generate assembly or IR in release mode. The attribute `#[inline(never)]` is often useful to keep functions separate to find them easier in the output.

Benchmarking is [documented in The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/benchmark-tests.html), so there's no need to repeat all that valuable information.

---

Before **Rust 1.14**, these do not produce the *exact* same assembly. I'd wait for benchmarking / profiling data to see if there's any meaningful impact on performance before I worried.

As of **Rust 1.14**, they *do produce the same assembly*! This is one reason I love Rust. You can write clear and idiomatic code and [smart people come along and make it equally as fast](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37315).

> but the first code would iterate two times, once for the `map` and once for the `sum`.

This is incorrect, and I'd love to know what source told you this so we can go correct it at that point and prevent future misunderstandings. [An iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html) operates on a pull basis; one element is processed at a time. The core method is `next`, which yields a single value, running just enough computation to produce that value.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's fix those example to actually return the same result:

```
pub fn total_fold_iter() -> u64 {
    (1..65).fold(0u64, |r, s| r + square(s))
}

pub fn total_map_iter() -> u64 {
    (1..65).map(square).sum()
}
```

Now, let's develop them, starting with `fold`. A `fold` is just a loop and an accumulator, it is **roughly** equivalent to:

```
pub fn total_fold_explicit() -> u64 {
    let mut total = 0;
    for i in 1..65 {
        total = total + square(i);
    }
    total
}
```

Then, let's go with `map` and `sum`, and unwrap the `sum` first, which is **roughly** equivalent to:

```
pub fn total_map_partial_iter() -> u64 {
    let mut total = 0;
    for i in (1..65).map(square) {
        total += i;
    }
    total
}
```

It's just a simple accumulator! And now, let's unwrap the `map` layer (which only applies a function), obtaining something that is **roughly** equivalent to:

```
pub fn total_map_explicit() -> u64 {
    let mut total = 0;
    for i in 1..65 {
        let s = square(i);
        total += s;
    }
    total
}
```

As you can see, the both of them are *extremely* similar: they have apply the same operations in the same order and have the same overall complexity.

---

Which is faster? I have no idea. And a micro-benchmark may only tell half the truth anyway: just because something is faster in a micro-benchmark does not mean it is faster in the midst of other code.

What I *can* say, however, is that they both have equivalent complexity and therefore should behave similarly, ie within a factor of each other.

And that I would personally go for `map` + `sum`, because it expresses the intent more clearly whereas `fold` is the "kitchen-sink" of `Iterator` methods and therefore far less informative.

Comment: The transformation that you apply to get the "plain" for loops is not how the compiler works. Perhaps after many optimizations it winds up with something similar (in fact I have little doubt that the two iterator chains wind up with the equivalent machine code), but that it *not* how the compiler desugars the two iterator chains. By contrast, the loops that you do end up with are so obviously equivalent that they should generate literally the same code &mdash; the differences are entirely cosmetic even to the compiler.

Comment: I don't think it has any impact on this scenario (who knows) but `.map()` just learned to pass on the fold, so it's now doing part of that rewriting explicitly, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37315

Comment: @delnan Minus some extremely minor nitpicks, it seems almost exactly like what the compiler sees after inlining. At what point do you disagree?

Comment: @Veedrac As I said, I do not dispute that morally similar code comes out after you ran the optimization pipeline over it, but I find the presentation in this answer too simplistic. It is not the case that the compiler applies one cute little high-level rewriting after the other (with exception of the recent PR bluss linked to). Even after inlining, it first sees a big ol' mess of nested matches on Options which is then optimized further. The performance of iterators is a consequence of inlining plus plain old straight-line-code optimizations [cont'd]

Comment: [...] and pretending the compiler works on a higher level does a disservice to the programmer. One needs to keep that in mind what the compiler can and can't to write code that optimizes well, and to be able to cope when the compiler *doesn't* optimize everything as you want. Besides, it's important to me that people don't mistake iterators for magic sauce. Anyone can write library code that optimizes just as well.

Comment: @delnan: That's a fair criticism; I was more interested in ensuring that there is no misunderstanding about the overall algorithm complexity (O(N)) than in the details.

Comment: @delnan I mean, OK, it happens inside LLVM's IR rather than at language level and the `for` loop is syntactically expanded, but the inlining still follows pretty much what was given.

Comment: @delnan i.e., for the first one the compiler inlines fold. [See definition.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/src/core/up/src/libcore/iter/iterator.rs.html#1306) The closure is a direct call because of monomorphisation, so will be inlined almost immidiately too. This gets the first code, except the iterator is evaluated earlier and passed down by value.

Comment: @delnan For the second the compiler inlines Sum::sum, [which is just a fold](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/src/core/up/src/libcore/iter/traits.rs.html#591), so that fold and its function argument then get inlined. Ignoring where the argument is evaluated, that's the first step given. The hardest to visualise step is inlining the map call because [you inline twice inside the for loop, and fold some branches on constants](https://gist.github.com/47c793db3ceb810b2f6445ff4c63122c). These are basic optimizations for LLVM, though.

Comment: @bluss By Jove, you've done it again! See my update above, but diffing the assembly in nightly shows they only differ in basic block names. Kudos!

Comment: Good, and the prize in crosshairs is worth even more than this example, see the VecDeque improvement or corresponding ndarray ones for .fold(). Segmented/nested iteration is seldom as optimizable when `Iterator::next` becomes a state machine; in the fold method we have the opportunity to write plain nested loops instead.