# How can you get the sum of all keys in an array of structs?

Tags: arrays, rust, sum

I have this struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    myvalue: u32,
    yourvalue: u32,
}
```

If I have `a: Vec<MyStruct>` how can I get the sum of all `MyStruct.myvalue`? I'm looking for something like `a.iter.sum(sum of myvalue)`.

I know I can do it with a `for` loop, but I would like to be able to do this with one line of code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To sum `MyStruct.myvalue` in a single line you can use [`Iterator::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) and [`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum).

```
fn sum_myvalue(a: &[MyStruct]) -> u32 {
    a.iter().map(|s| s.myvalue).sum()
}

// Later on you can use this like so:
//
sum_myvalue(a);
```

See also:

- [Is `iter().map().sum()` as fast as `iter().fold()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40441334/155423)